# Minimum number of lines needed to divide a 2d plane

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, trigonometry, combinatorial-geometry

I was thinking about this problem, and have searched online to see if there has been work done on this, but have not found anything.

The question is if I wanted to divide a plane into n unique regions, what is the minimum number of lines needed? 
[here's an illustration of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOPXK.gif)

I did find the formula 0.5(n²+n+2) which gives the maximum number of spaces given a line n. While very related, it's almost the reverse of my question.

I did work on coming up with experimental values [given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikn88.png). There does seem to be a clear pattern, except for when n=5, which would throw the whole thing off.

Comment: You could easily produce $5$ regions with $3$ lines!

Comment: @mjw No of course not: the possible configurations of three lines are all parallel (four regions), all three intersecting (six regions), two parallel and the third not (six regions), and general position (seven regions).

Comment: I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

This is hand-wavy but if you know that you can create *at most* $M$ regions with $N$ lines (let's call this $f(N) = M$), then I'd think that you could create fewer than $M$ regions with $N$ lines.  (This is an assumption.)

Let's arrange these maximum numbers as a sequence: $f(1), f(2), f(3), ... \to M_1, M_2, M_3, ...$

So, for any particular number of $m$ regions, the fewest number of lines needed will be the value $j$, such that $M_{j-1} < m \leq M_j$.